# Re-register GCM id unsuccessfull in background?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I do not know what happened to my application, I can't re-register my GCM, first I try register GCM to server and successfully, I can send and receive messages via the GCM, but some days I get my GCM_id is not registered, I get this log.

```
{"multicast_id":7940813116785473128,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

I tried to come back to register but my registration failed because the GCM_id have listed a registered,here the log from device

```
10-11 16:26:53.110: I/GCMIntentService(11303): myREGID : APA91bHfpPgeUBAEPqv7f6TYKpAzP0Mngcxdkgy0ycRBOLasuSmMkAOQm4xRmyLT7vsjtWOhfaN9pRaK5xAKRcVOAKhmQdC0Vm7JNGY-qJB9jcD8M0OfjtWQyTuMVzUzh1aBKArfwKO9HxF6nKqK8snflRFQ
10-11 16:26:53.150: V/GCMRegistrar(11303): Is registered on server: true
10-11 16:26:53.150: V/AndroidGCM(11303): Posting 'regId=APA91bHfpPgeUBAEPqv7f6TYKpAzP0Mngcxdkgy0ycRBOLasuSmMkAOQm4xRmyLT7vsjtWOhfaN9pRaK5xAKRcVOAKhmQdC0Vm7JNGY-qJB9jcD8M0OfjtWQyTuMVzUzh1aBKArfwKO9HxF6nKqK8qrcD1PDnflRFQ' to example.org/gcmServer/register.php/unregister
10-11 16:26:53.400: V/GCMRegistrar(11303): Setting registeredOnServer status as false until 2014-10-18 16:26:53.405
10-11 16:26:53.470: I/AndroidGCM(11303): registering device (regId = APA91bHfpPgeUBAEPqv7f6TYKpAzP0Mngcxdkgy0ycRBOLasuSmMkAOQm4xRmyLT7vsjtWOhfaN9pRaK5xAKRcVOAKhmQdC0Vm7JNGY-qJB9jcD8M0OfjtWQyTuMVzUzh1aBKArfwKO9HxF6nKqK8qrcD1PDnflRFQ)
10-11 16:26:53.470: V/AndroidGCM(11303): Posting 'noHP=00000&pwd=xxx&email=ltv@ltv.com&regId=APA91bHfpPgeUBAEPqv7f6TYKpAzP0Mngcxdkgy0ycRBOLasuSmMkAOQm4xRmyLT7vsjtWOhfaN9pRaK5xAKRcVOAKhmQdC0Vm7JNGY-qJB9jcD8M0OfjtWQyTuMVzUzh1aBKArfwKO9HxF6nKqK8qrcD1PDnflRFQ&name=lutfi' to example.com/gcmServer/register.php
10-11 16:26:53.720: V/GCMRegistrar(11303): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2014-10-18 16:26:53.723
```

I am confused, in server I get my id GCM is not listed but in device i got my GCM id registered, because I can not register directly I have to uninstall my app to be able to register and get a new GCM id. but it is not a solution, I want when I get status GCM id not registered so I immediately re-registration through the background, I use php as GCM server.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Your question is related to re-registration GCM, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398567/explicitly-re-register-device-to-gcm